# CUPS connection refused

Tags: drivers, printing

I have been printing with cups for about 2 months(nothing expert, just add driver/print) and today I wanted to install driver for  printer EPSON Stylus Photo PX730. I have installed it firstly through printers-add printer and then selected the driver, but that did not work for me(exclamation mark near printer) so i deleted it and then by inserting PPD into cups(it looked successful) but now I cannot access my localhost:631.
Firefox will say `Unable to connect` and chromium `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.
I have tried

```
apt-get remove cups
dpkg --purge cups
apt-get install cups
dpkg-reconfigure cups
```

and also installing cups from rpm package, but i think it was not successful. I am using Linux Mint 17.2, 64-bit. If thats not obvious from my post, i am beginner with linux at this time. Thank you all

Comment: For others having the same issue, it could just be that `cups` is not started via `/etc/init.d/cups start`

Comment: @JIXiang worked for me, you should post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that `cups` has not been started yet. You may try to run `/etc/init.d/cups start`.